# PHP/RewriteRule: GET variables don't get passed through

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file that routes all traffic through a frontloading index.php file using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [PT]
```

But the $_GET varaibles don't get passed for some reason..

In the index.php when I var_dump the $_GET, all I get is

```
array(1) { ["index_php"]=> string(0) "" }
```

no matter what is in the query string.

What do I need to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
index.php?page=$1
```

You have to define a parameter for that value.  If you want all query string values you can add `{QUERY_STRING}` after `$1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **query string append** flag at the end of your rewrite rule. Place `[QSA]` at the end of the rewrite rule you would like to retain any `$_GET` variables. Remember, that if you'd like to use the `[L]` flag as well, you would write `[QSA,L]`.

[mod_rewrite - Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong. Of you want get www.adress.com/page/5/comments create rule like it.